# How to avoid font scaling in React Native Application with device font

Tags: android, react-native

How to stop scaling the font size of React Native Application when the device font size is scaling up in Android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried out with the following code. It helped to avoid font scaling in Text fields in React Native Application.

I edited App.js with the following code.

```
if (Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```